# DBIx::Class : Resultset order_by based upon existence of a value in the list

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

I am using DBIx::Class and I have got a ResultSet. I like to re-order the ResultSet. I like to check a particular column "City" against a  fix list of values ("London", "New York" "Tokyo")  If  city is found in the list of values   I like to move that result to the top group.  If city is not found, I like to move that result to the bottom group in the ResultSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ORDER BY expr](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/order-by-the-lesser-known-way-2008-10-27/) might be what you're looking for.

For example, here a table:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | London    |
|  2 | Paris     |
|  3 | Tokio     |
|  4 | Rome      |
|  5 | Amsterdam |
+----+-----------+
```

Here the special ordering:

```
mysql> select * from test order by name = 'London' desc, 
                                   name = 'Paris'  desc, 
                                   name = 'Amsterdam' desc;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | London    |
|  2 | Paris     |
|  5 | Amsterdam |
|  3 | Tokio     |
|  4 | Rome      |
+----+-----------+
```

Translating this into a ResultSet method:

```
$schema->resultset('Test')->search(
    {},
    {order_by => {-desc => q[name in ('London', 'New York', 'Tokyo')] }}
);
```

Comment: With which version this works? It doesn't work with DBIx::Class 0.08123. I did not see any reference in  SQL::Abstract also, but that may not mean much.

Comment: Is it possible to create additional dynamic field and do order_by on the new field?

Comment: The example added by daxim (thank you for editing, btw, my last sentence was a bit vague :) is not exactly what it was meant to be. You can specify a reference to a string for the order_by param, so you can dinamically build a string like "name = 'London' desc, name = 'Paris' desc, name = 'Tokyo' desc"

Comment: Oracle Database is not accepting the query thus geneated. Oracle uses 'decode' for this. Is there a way around?

Comment: In Oracle, you can use an ORDER BY CASE expression, explained here: http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/CASE-expressions-in-the-ORDER-BY-clause (I don't have an Oracle installation offhand to try, sorry)

Comment: Here is a better example and works fine with my installation. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0040__Query-Select/Combineorderbyclausewithcasestatement.htm  Now, how I can use with DBIC?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $what = shift or die;
my @ary  = qw(alpha beta gamma);
unshift(@ary,$what) unless ( grep(/$what/,@ary) );
print "@ary\n";
1;
```

Run as:

```
./myscript omega
```

Comment: I am looking for dbic answer.